# Phonegap Build Open all external links on default browser

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I am working on a phonegap build project and I need to open all external links on the default browser.

I've tried this setting:

```
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
```

but that's not opening the link in the default browser.

How can I get all external links to open in the default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correct, you need to use the plugin [`org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1169) which hooks the `window.open` function, and adds the new *_system* target (this opens the default web browser).

So you can force your links to use `window.open` like this (jQuery):

```js
$('a').click(function() {
    if (this.host !== window.location.host) {
        window.open(this.href, '_system');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```